# How do I Count cells in excel, starting with a cell that has a specified value?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]The question is slightly confusing, so I will do my best to elaborate. I have a series of cells in a row with all of the cells in the row with a value of 0 and one cell having a value of 1. I want to use the COUNT function to count all of the cells to the right of the cell that contains the value of 1, including that cell. I would then use this number of counted cells in another equation. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? I have tried using a lookup function inside of the count function, but it has not worked. This is my closest guess:

```
=COUNT(Lookup(1,A1:J1):J1)
```

This results in an error. Do I need to use VBA to make this work or should I be able to write an equation? I appreciate the help, or if there are any other strategies that I can use to attain the result I am looking for.

Edit: I am adding in some sample data and expected results. I am trying to count all of the cells to the right of the "1" including the cell containing the "1". So in this example, I would expect the formula to return "13" as there are 12 cells to the right of the "1"

[image: Here is a sample picture of the data]

Comment: Are the values in a row, or in a column?  Your description has "row" but your formula suggests "column".

Comment: Sounds like `=11-MATCH(1,A1:A10,0)` (but as Tim pointed out, that is working on a column but your question refers to rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your range of `0` and `1` values is in row 2, starting from column B, use this formula in B3 and copy it across for as far as you need:

```
=IFERROR(COUNT($B2:B2)+1-MATCH(1,$B2:B2,0),0)
```

[image]

---

You could also use a formula of

```
=IF(A3>0,1+A3,IF(B2=1,1,0))
```

but that could cause issues if you have something in cell A3 itself.

Comment: For my purposes this formula is simple and replicable. A perfect fit, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use OFFSET() and MATCH():

[image]

That last "50" is a bit of a guess since I'm not sure how far to the right you want to count...

...and re-reading your question it's not clear if you only want to count values of 1 or if you also need to count other values as long as they're to the right of the first 1.

Comment: FWIW - my interpretation of "a row with all of the cells in the row with a value of 0 and one cell having a value of 1" is that the OP has a lot of `0`s, with one `1` amongst them, so your code should work nicely.

Comment: @YowE3K - I think it would be v. useful if the OP updated their question to add some sample data and expected results.

Comment: The one issue I can see with your formula is that you use `50` to define a "maximum" width of cells to be counted, but then hardcode `A2:I2` which means that you are already assuming a "maximum" of 9 cells in which to locate the `1`.  Would it be slightly more generic to use `2:2` instead of `A2:I2`?

Comment: @YowE3K - I was unsure how far to the right the user wanted to go and didn't want to over-work the formula to make is account for the starting point in the width of the area returned from OFFSET, so I just made a guess.  Assuming the OP could figure out how to tweak it to meet their needs.

Comment: My data does appear as @YowE3K has elaborated. This is very helpful, and will hopefully solve my issue. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @TimWilliams this is definitely a great response and on the right track, however I am still not getting the results I am looking for. I understand my problem now is that I have many more zeroes extending past the certain point I want to count to. For example, I want my count to end in column J, but I have data extending out to column BB. Any suggestions?? Thank you for your help.

Comment: "I want my count to end at column J" and 'So in this example, I would expect the formula to return "13" as there are 12 cells to the right of the "1"' seem to be contradictory?  And what exactly do you want to count - empty cells, cells with zeroes, cells with numbers, or what?  Your question really needs some clarification: your use of `COUNT()` is misleading if you don't want to count only numbers for example

Comment: I want the formula to return 13, because as I stated in the question, I want the formula to return the count of all the cells to the right of the "1" as well as the cell that contains the value of "1", I'm sorry if that is misleading. Secondly, all of the cells after the cell with the value of "1" have a value of "0". I need to be able to copy this formula across, so the result for the range of cells A1:J1 would for example be 5, and then A1:K1 would be 6, and etc. I have added another picture in my question above to clarify my necessity.

Comment: @TimWilliams I forgot to tag you to see my comment above

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1** through **J1**, consider:

```
=10-MATCH(1,A1:J1,0)+1
```

[image]

In this case. ***4*** is the number of cells from **G1** through **J1**, inclusive.

Comment: This is helpful, but it is not replicable. Is there a solution I could use for multiple ranges of cells? For example, a formula that could work for bot a range of 10 cells and a range of 15 cells?

Comment: @ChaseGarfield  I understand.....for an arbitrary set of cells in the row use.... **=COUNT(A1:J1)-MATCH(1,A1:J1,0)+1**  this avoids using ***10*** as a "magic number"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=COUNTA(INDEX($A$1:$J$1,1,MATCH(1,$A$1:$J$1,0)):INDEX($A$1:$J$1,1,10))
```

[image]

The benefit to use this is it is not a volatile function, and it will also work for `1` appears in the last column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "COUNTIF" formula to count number of occurrences of specific number in a range of cells.

To count no of occurrences in a row.

> =COUNTIF(1:1,1)

If it is in a column then

> =COUNTIF(A:A,1)

Comment: The OP's statement "I have a series of cells in a row with all of the cells in the row with a value of 0 and **one cell having a value of 1**" would imply that a `COUNTIF` for cells matching `1` will return an answer of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for a countif function.

```
COUNTIF(A1:A10, 1)
```

The above function counts the cell that has value 1 within the range A1:A10

Comment: The OP's statement "I have a series of cells in a row with all of the cells in the row with a value of 0 and **one cell having a value of 1**" would imply that a `COUNTIF` for cells matching `1` will return an answer of 1.